# Existing Email Service to new System for existing Applicatons

Tags: sql-server, web-services, email, sqlclr, service-broker

We have a current system where emails are triggering from different apps mostly from database(stored procedures) and will be inserted entry to a common table. Email Service system will read from this table and send emails to the users.

We are planning to integrate a new system where the emails can be send using a web service. We need to send data to this web service and service will take care of sending emails.

We need a solution to invoke this email web service(WCF) from database and below are the two thoughts we have.

1. Create a CLR function which calls the service
2. Service Broker

Any help on this highly appreciable.

Comment: Instead of using either SQLCLR or SSB - can't you use DB Mail?

Comment: Oh, and how were you thinking of using SSB? With an external activator or what? My point with this is that if you were not thinking of using an external activator, you'd still need SQLCLR.

Comment: Why are you moving away from the current Email Service? What is better about the new web service? What is the frequency of sending emails / how many per second or minute? Why are you using Email Service instead of DBMail (as Niels suggested in the first comment) since DBMail is queued / asynchronous? While Service Broker with external activation is probably the way to go, it is also wasted effort since that is exactly how DBMail works, so why duplicate unless you have a specific need that DBMail can't provide. Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: @NielsBerglund, we are using DBmails in some places like if there is any failure in jobs or some critical stored procedures, we will trigger a mail to concerned team. But the frequency for other mails is bit high like per day 2k-5k mails will be triggered.

Comment: @NielsBerglund, for SSB we are planning to use external activator which calls the service.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky current email system is a legacy system and new system has the feature to send text message and emails hence planning to use it for both. The frequency is like per day 2-5K mails based on user activities(200K+ users). Current version is Sql Server 2017 enterprise. Client has different services and they need a common system through which the email service has to be processed. That's why changing to new system.

Comment: @Keppy, If you cannot use existing DBMail, then I'd suggest SSB with eternal activator. Another suggestion would be to use Query Notifications on the email table, and have an external service reading off the table and process (actually, that's more or less what SSB with EA would be doing).

Comment: @NielsBerglund, awesome. thanks for your help.